# Changing an Ext.panel title

Tags: extjs4

I'd like to dynamically set the panel title. And the following doesn't seem to work! Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
       id: 'p0',
       title: 'Hello World',
       width: 200,
       html: '<p>Lorem ispsum doler sit</p>',
       renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.getCmp('p0').title = 'Bye World'; //does not work!    
Ext.getCmp('p0').header.title = 'Bye World'; //does not work either!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply call the `setTitle` method available with the `Panel` class.

```
panel.setTitle('Bye World');
```

[Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-setTitle) is your friend. Read it!!

Comment: Argh, can't believe I missed that! Thanks mate!